# FlipView SelectionChange C#

Tags: c#, flipview

I am making a simple metro app to display an image and some content relevant to the image.

Ex :
image : data
img1 : "Image of a butterfly"
img2 : "Hello sky"
img3 : "Picture of a Golden Retriever"

I have loaded images into a flipview.And relevent data into an array.

```
<FlipView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,147,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="627" Height="429" Name="fiImage" SelectionChanged="fiImage_SelectionChanged">
      <Image Source="Assets/image1.png"  Name="Img1" />
      <Image Source="Assets/image2.png"  Name="Img2" />
</FlipView>
```

I have a TextBlock in the xaml named as "tbN". What I want to do is when I change the image using pointer, relevant data should display in the textblock.

I tried following code at selection change event

```
private void fiImage_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int i = ((FlipView)sender).SelectedIndex;
    tbN.Text = a[i];  //error line
}
```

But when I execute the program, I get an error saying "NullReferenceException was unhandled by the user code: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

What am I missing?

Comment: Where is `tbN` defined? Where is `a` defined?

Comment: a is defined as a global variable. tbN is the textblock and I created it in the xaml.

Answer (score 0):

It seems **a[i]** has not being initialized and doesn't have values. Is it a global variable?.
Debug your code and check it's content. It must be null.

If it is not null, maybe that array doesn't have the **i** value. Or maybe it's exceding the array length.

```
tbN.Text = a[i]; //a[i] must be null, where is it initialized?
```

Comment: yes, it is a global variable. I tried to access values of array a using another method and that method works fine. but inside this selectionChanged method, it gives me that error.

Comment: Check the array values and length. Be sure the index of i exist in the array object.

Comment: when I debug the code, value of i is 0;
i have defined "a" like following
static string[] a = { "Hello", "2nd String", "Third String" };

Comment: And what is the length of array a[] and it's value at zero index?

Comment: If your control exists  and code is compiling it doesnt make sense

Comment: If i give you the project file, can you check it?

Answer (score 0):

SelectionChanged event fires at initialization as well (first child "selected").
Your control (tbN) does not exist at the time.

Check if tbN is null to avoid NRef. Exception!

```
private void fiImage_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (tbN != null)
    {
        int i = ((FlipView)sender).SelectedIndex;
        tbN.Text = a[i]; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution [HERE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7ef7c6a8-d8f8-44cb-b4c2-9efe7552a881/how-to-get-flipviewitem-inside-flipviewselectionchanged-event?forum=winappswithcsharp)

```
private void FlipView_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FlipView fv = sender as FlipView;
    if (fv.SelectedItem == null) return;
    var item = fv.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(fv.SelectedItem);
    if (item == null)
    {
        Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                var itemSecondTime = fv.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(fv.SelectedItem);
                if (itemSecondTime == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("no item.  Why????");
                }
            });
    }
}
```